# WPF exception handling when launched from WinForms

Tags: wpf, winforms

so i came across this interesting article on WPF exception handling:
http://srtsolutions.com/public/item/251263

it works by declaring DispatcherUnhandledException handler in xaml <application> node.

but what if a WPF window is launched from win forms application?

where can i declare a general exception handler?

The problem is that when WPF crashes, it brings down the whole WinForms app with it.

*Edit
what if instead of launching the WPF window directly, i launched an "Application" which than defined a start window?? is that possible/advisable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attach your handler to the `<obj>.Dispatcher.UnhandledException` event, where `<obj>` is any WPF control, or another `DispatcherObject` that is created on the same thread.

Comment: any way you can elaborate on how to actually assign the handler to the dispatcher? UnhandledException is not really a property of it..

Comment: It's not a property, but an event. Use the usual `+=` syntax. Check out documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.unhandledexception.aspx

Comment: poor choice of words, i meant that, that event is not available on my windows dispatcher object.

Comment: How is that? I mean, how do you know that it's not available?

Comment: actually, it is there, my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the traditional "global" exception handlers for Windows Forms would apply here:

Hook the thread exception as the first line in Main:

```
Application.ThreadException += new ThreadExceptionEventHandler(new ThreadExceptionHandler().ApplicationThreadException);
```

Comment: thanks, 
that is actually already implemented. but any WPF exception still nukes the container winforms app.